# Solve double recursive sequence

Tags: recurrence-relations

I want to find a closed form of $a_i$ sequence below:

$$a_i = \alpha a_{i-1} + \beta b_{i-1}$$
$$b_i = \gamma a_{i-1} + \delta b_{i-1}$$

I did some expansions and arrived to (assuming I have no errors) something that looks simpler:

$$a_i = f(i) + \sum_{j=1}^i j\delta^ja_j$$

But solving the second term is something I can not figure out as well.

Comment: Do you have specific values for $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$? There are general methods to solve such recurrences. Your recurrence is of the form $\mathbf{x}_{i} = A\mathbf{x}_{i-1}$, where $A = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha & \beta \\ \gamma & \delta \end{bmatrix}$ and $\mathbf{x}_{n} = \begin{bmatrix} a_{n} \\ b_{n}\end{bmatrix}$. You can show that this implies that $\mathbf{x}_{i} = A^{i}\mathbf{x}_{0}$ for all $i\in \mathbb{N}$. So if you have learnt about how to find powers of a matrix, you could go from here.

Comment: You can also try to eliminate one of the variables and end up with a second-order linear recurrence for the other, which you can then solve if you have learnt about how to solve these (for some examples and information about this, see [here](https://math.berkeley.edu/~arash/55/8_2.pdf) for instance). For example, see the example from slide 43 [here](http://cs.indstate.edu/~arash/adslec7.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem can be written like this:

$$
\mathbf{x}_i = \begin{bmatrix} a_i \\ b_i \end{bmatrix} = \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}_{i-1} \hspace{20mm} \mathbf{A} = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha & \beta \\ \gamma & \delta \end{bmatrix}
$$

Assume you know $\mathbf{x}_0$.  Then $\mathbf{x}_i = \mathbf{A}^i \mathbf{x}_0$.

Here are the first few values of $\mathbf{A}^n$.
$$
\mathbf{A}^0 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}  \\
\mathbf{A}^1 = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha & \beta \\ \gamma & \delta \end{bmatrix}  \\
\mathbf{A}^2 = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha^2 + \beta\gamma & \alpha\beta + \beta\delta \\ \alpha\gamma + \gamma\delta & \beta\gamma + \delta^2 \end{bmatrix}  \\
$$

I believe that for arbitrary $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$, you will need to compute $\mathbf{A}^n$ explicitly.  See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301000/how-to-calculate-square-matrix-to-power-n) on how to calculate square matrix powers.  If your matrix $\mathbf{A}$ satisfies a recurrence relation, then you can obtain a closed-form solution.

Answer (score 3):

The defining matrix $A$ has trace $T = \alpha + \delta$ and determinant $D = \alpha \delta - \beta \gamma .$ The Cayley-Hamilton Theorem says
$$ A^2 - TA + DI = 0,  $$
$$ A^2 = TA - DI. $$
In particular,
$$  a_{i+2} = T a_{i+1} - D a_i   $$